# React - Can I create a last function to load when all else has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node.js

Learning React so please bear with...

I would like to perform a task when the entire app has finished loading.

I am making an API call to gathering dataSets, based on the users selection from a number of check boxes.

This can be a small data set or a very large data (the results spread across many pages.)

So far im using a timer...
After 8 seconds...(8 seconds because that is the time it takes to load the page when maximum data set is returned)..so this is a sure bet to do what I want...But I dont want to use a timer. what if the user selects a 2 second result, and then another 3? I would have missed this with an 8 sec timer. I would like to call my function when the app itself has finished loading, wether it is 3 seconds or 8.

I am having difficulty doing this.

Say for exmaple

```
export MainComponent()
componenet1()
componenet2()
componenet3()
```

Inside component2 is where I am saying check if element exists by className, if it does do this. The reason I need the maximum timer is because any less and if the page has not finished loading it will return the wrong results.

I have tried to add a console.log in many places to try and find this...
exmaple inside my body tag in the index.js

```
<body onload="console.log('The Script will load now.')">
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
```

also tried componentDidUpdate and componentDidMount from inside componenet2() but this didnt work either...Then created an export function in a page which I can call globally so I can use in componenet1() 2 or 3...and this works..

but again if the user choses the option for a 3 second load, quickly views the results and choses another option for a 2 second result...I am not getting the correct results...

So when the entire app has finished loading I would like to call exmaple..

```
LastToLoad()
{
let count = document.getElementsByClassName('BlueScreen').length;
//the issue being if the app hasnt finished loading and I call this function too soon, I get the wrong count.
if(count > 0)
{

...do something
}
{
```

any help please?

Comment: i would encourage you to take a look at promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and to the use of states https://react.dev/learn/managing-state

Comment: Do you have a sample app/codebase that you can share? The question appears to be very broad and more context is needed. Can you create a simpler version of what you're trying to do in https://codesandbox.io/ and share it if possible?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was just seeing if its possible to have a final function which is loaded when called from anywhere in my application, that will call when everything on screen has loaded?? Is this even possible?